# Hyperlink text inside lstlisting

Tags: hyperref, listings

I was wondering whether or not is possible to make a text (clickable or not) inside `lstlisting` which redirects to a figure in the document for example. Something like this:

```
...

\begin{figure}[t]
    \includegraphics{myfigure} 
\label{figx}
\end{figure}

...

\begin{lstlisting}
# plot figure~\hyperref[figx]{\ref{figx}}
some code
\end{lstlisting}

...
```

Thanks in advance for sharing any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include more or less any LaTeX macro you want inside your listing by defining a way to *escape* from verbatim code formatting to usual LaTeX processing. Here is an example using `escapeinside` to define two sequences of chars that start (`/*!`) and end (`!*/`) the escape area. I usually use the usual comment delimiters of the respective language plus some characters I usually don't use in comments, such that the code still looks good in editors without LaTeX parsing (but you can really use any delimiters you like).

**Update:** You can also use the options `escapebegin` and `escapeend` to add some LaTeX macros around the escaped sequence. Suppose you always use the escape in comments and have comments printed in gray, you can pass the `escapebegin=\color{gray}` option to have the escaped text printed in the same color.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=C++,
    commentstyle=\color{gray},
    escapeinside={/*!}{!*/},
    escapebegin=\color{gray},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My figure}
    \label{figx}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}
void test() {
    figure->display(); // Output: /*!\ref{figx}!*/
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tiuri, it works pretty well. My smaller problem is that the escaped text is within a comment, which happens to be in gray color (but +1 to your answer).

Comment: @Toño I updated my answer to show how you can include colors (or any other formatting macros) easily to the escape area.

Comment: Yeps, I wanted to get that argument in the `lstset`. Thnx