# index{} reference inside lstlisting when using matlab-prettifier

Tags: indexing, matlab-prettifier

I have been using matlab-prettifier with success. But when I tried to add index 'references' inside the MATLAB comments I ran into trouble.

I tried to implement the StackExchange suggestion given in 'Hyperlink text inside lstlisting' ([Hyperlink text inside lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413891/hyperlink-text-inside-lstlisting))

It looks nice, but didn't work for me, when I tried to add \index{} calls inside the comments of a Matlab script.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{listings} % not required

\usepackage[framed,numbered]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{
    style      = Matlab-editor,
    %escapeinside={/*!}{!*/}
    escapeinside={/**}{**/}
}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
 \index{example!first}
 
 \begin{lstlisting}[style=Matlab-editor, caption = {Simple example of index call inside lstlisting}]
    for ii = 1:6
    Disp(s(ii)) 
    end
    %
    % EXAMPLE: let b = 7 /**\index{example!second}**/
    %
    >> b = 7    
    
    b =
    
    7
    % Unfortunately the index call spoils the rest of the script
\end{lstlisting}    
 \printindex
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help